# How do I construct a Minimum Spanning Tree from a list of vertexes, using QuikGraph C#?

Tags: c#, game-engine, minimum-spanning-tree, procedural-generation

How do I get from a list of vertexes/nodes to a graph that I can use with **QuikGraph** to e.g. produce a Minimum Spanning Tree?

EDIT:(
I've been forward and backward over the QuikGraph wiki https://github.com/KeRNeLith/QuikGraph and every example I can find glosses over graph *creation*
)

**Background**

My program procedurally generates game levels. My plan is to use an `UndirectedGraph` from **QuikGraph** to store the level information, so I can use library functions to semi-intelligently lay out level content, set up patrols, etc.

*My first stage* packs the level with rooms based on configurable parameters.
*My second stage* seeks to connect the rooms with the minimum amount of nonsense hallways - ie, connecting adjacent rooms with a single direct hallway. I will break some connections and add other connections later. This *seems* like a simple case of building a minimum spanning tree.

I expected to find some sort of algorithm that takes a list of graph nodes (and some method of determining the weight/distance between any two graph nodes), and return a list of edges or something. I can't seem to find that - everything seems to assume you already have a list of edges, ie an existing graph.

What's the best way to set this up? "A list of all possible combination of edges between nodes" seems crazy, but I can't think of anything else.

**Note**

I'm not working with a game engine. The output is intended to be a static text description suitable for use by a human when setting up a pen-and-paper roleplaying game. All the graphics and input handling and physics and sound and network and etc are overkill...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received some good advice on how to prepare my graph - using a Delaunay triangulation routine will set up a graph connected by proximity, and efficiently. I found the Delaunator library on NuGet, which seems to be doing the job well.